# Gremlin : How do you find vertex and edges when some edges does not exists

Tags: gremlin

I am new to gremlin.
I am facing issue in fetching the vertex and edges when sometimes edge from a vertex does not exists.
for example bellow query works fine if it gets all the vertex and edges.
but for one use case edge

```
`.outE("PRODUCES").`as`("produces"))`
```

does not exists in db.

in that case bellow query doesnt return any result.
I need your help to resolve this issue.
when edges does not exit then i want input_entity and processed_by in result.

```
janusGraph.traversal().V()
.has("isActive", "true")
.hasLabel("ENTITY").`as`("input_entity")
.outE("PROCESSED_BY").`as`("processed_by")
.inV().`as`("job")
.outE("PRODUCES").`as`("produces")
.select<String>("job").outE("HAS_STATE")
.`as`("job_state_edge").inV().hasLabel("JOB_STATE").`as`("job_state")

.select<String>("input_entity").outE("HAS_STATE")
.`as`("input_entity_state_edge").inV().hasLabel("ENTITY_STATE").`as`("input_entity_state")
.select<String>("input_entity").outE("CONNECTS_TO").`as`("connects_to")

.inV().hasLabel("ENTITY").has("entityName", TextP.startingWith(rootNamespace))
.`as`("output_entity").outE("HAS_STATE")
.`as`("output_entity_state_edge").inV().hasLabel("ENTITY_STATE").`as`("output_entity_state")

.select<String>("input_entity","output_entity","processed_by","produces","job","job_state","input_entity_state","output_entity_state","input_entity_state_edge","output_entity_state_edge","job_state_edge","connects_to")
.by(elementMap<Element, Any>()).toList()
```

with optional

```
janusGraph.traversal().V()
.has("isActive", "true")
.hasLabel("ENTITY").`as`("input_entity")
.outE("HAS_STATE").`as`("input_entity_state_edge").inV().hasLabel("ENTITY_STATE").`as`("input_entity_state")
.select<String>("input_entity").outE("PROCESSED_BY").`as`("processed_by")
.inV().`as`("job").outE("HAS_STATE").`as`("job_state_edge").inV().hasLabel("JOB_STATE").`as`("job_state")
.select<String>("job")
.optional(
    outE("PRODUCES").`as`("produces")
.select<String>("input_entity").outE("CONNECTS_TO").`as`("connects_to")
.inV().hasLabel("ENTITY").has("entityName", TextP.startingWith(rootNamespace))
.`as`("output_entity").outE("HAS_STATE").`as`("output_entity_state_edge").inV().hasLabel("ENTITY_STATE").`as`("output_entity_state"))
.select<String>("input_entity","output_entity","processed_by","produces","job","job_state","input_entity_state","output_entity_state","input_entity_state_edge","output_entity_state_edge","job_state_edge","connects_to")
.by(elementMap<Element, Any>()).toList()
```

Comment: What result would you like to get when the edge does not exist?  Can you please add that to the question? You likely want to explore the `coalesce` and `optional` Gremlin steps.

Comment: @KelvinLawrence edited question : when edges does not exit then i want input_entity and processed_by in result.

Comment: @KelvinLawrence : as you said i used optional. but since in the last lines of query i am using select that contains those elements also which is not yet evaluated like output_entity_state, connects_to. so query fails. if i just select the elements before optional then it works. like if use   input_entity in select (before toList()). i added query with optional in question.

Comment: You probably want to wrap the `select` in a `coalesce` where you return some default value if the `select` fails.

Comment: I'll have a go at writing up an answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are two Gremlin steps that can help in cases like this. When you have a part of a query that may or may not exist, but you either want the results up to that point if it does not exist or the results afterwards if it does exist, you can wrap that part of the query in an `optional` step.

For example :

```java
g.V('3').optional(out())
```

Will either return V['3'] or the adjacent vertices if `out` yields results.

In cases where you want to select a value that may not exist, you can do something like this:

```java
coalesce(select('a'),constant('No results'))
```

EDITED to add:

If you need to return multiple results, rather than just using `select` try a `project('a','b,',c')` type of approach where each `by` modulator for the `project` can contain its own `coalesce` step.

Comment: in my case i need to select multiple values. if i replace  select in last lines with `.coalesce(select<String, String>("input_entity","output_entity","processed_by","produces","job","job_state","input_entity_state","output_entity_state","input_entity_state_edge","output_entity_state_edge","job_state_edge","connects_to"))`      then it does not work.

Comment: Perhaps rather than just using `select` try a `project('a','b,',c')` type of approach where each `by` modulator for the `project` can contain its own `coalesce` step.